# Logmein has completely stopped working on MACOSX 10.7.1

Tags: macos, logmein

I've used logmein for around 8 months or so on my mac. Since upgrading to OSX Lion I didn't have any problems. But it seems that this problem has started a few days since updating to 10.7.1 last month. I can get into the GUI of logmein, but as soon as I press turn on the whole interface completely freezes. You cannot click on anything, but the app is responding (as in, it isn't actually frozen). The service doesn't start. I have tried completely uninstalling the software using the uninstaller, and also using appdelete -  no joy. I have removed the computer from the account on the web site, and re-added it. Same problem. Tried permissions repair, and running ONYX - cleaning everything. No joy. What could be the problem? Other computer on the same account works ok.

Comment: I can't give a solution but I can give an alternative, use Teamviewer, Free which accomplishes what you need. http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx

Comment: I have teamviewer. One annoying thing is I can't seem to remove the dock icon and stick it on the menu bar. Not even speaking about proper auto-starting it. And I've got a few computers in logmein. Plus it's accessible with just a browser - always handy.

Answer (score 0):

ALthough you removed and reinstalled the app, it may have left settings around - either in a dotfile (unix style), or in your Library directory.

What you could do is perform the uninstall.
Then from a terminal:

`find ~/ -iname logmein`

You should delete all the results, and then try to reinstall it.

Comment: I have uninstalled logmein again. Tried putting this command into terminal before and after uninstallation. This is what I get: http://postimage.org/image/1vonrxe3o/